# SQL query for Slicing Dataset in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

Need some help/pointers with PostgreSQL query. I have a table with events from a system

Events:

```
id|          tstamp   |device_type
-----------------------------------
1 |2017-10-01 00:00:00|mobile
2 |2017-10-01 00:00:10|mobile
3 |2017-10-01 00:00:20|mobile
4 |2017-10-01 00:10:10|mobile
5 |2017-10-01 00:10:20|mobile
```

From this table, I could derive the lag between rows

```
    id|    tstamp     |device_type|lag_in_sec
-----------------------------------
1 |2017-10-01 00:00:00|mobile     |
2 |2017-10-01 00:00:10|mobile     | 10
3 |2017-10-01 00:00:20|mobile     | 10
4 |2017-10-01 00:10:20|mobile     | 600
5 |2017-10-01 00:10:30|mobile     | 10
```

Now, I would like to slice this table on based on lag if it is greater than 60 and get min and max tstamps in the slice. In this case, I'm trying to derive below output

```
 min_tstamp          |     max_tstamp
 ----------------------------------------
 2017-10-01 00:00:00 | 2017-10-01 00:00:20
 2017-10-01 00:10:20 | 2017-10-01 00:10:30
```

Any pointers to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to divide the records into groups based on the lag_in_sec values using a CASE expression, a subquery and `SUM over` analytic function, in this way:

```
SELECT tstamp, 
       SUM( CASE WHEN lag_in_sec >= interval '60' second THEN 1 ELSE 0 END )
       OVER (order by tstamp) as group_number
FROM ( 
   SELECT *, tstamp - lag( tstamp ) Over (order by tstamp) as lag_in_sec
   FROM Table1234
) x;

+----------------------+---------------+
|        tstamp        | ,group_number |
+----------------------+---------------+
| 2017-10-01 00:00:00, |             0 |
| 2017-10-01 00:00:10, |             0 |
| 2017-10-01 00:00:20, |             0 |
| 2017-10-01 00:10:10, |             1 |
| 2017-10-01 00:10:20, |             1 |
+----------------------+---------------+
```

---

ad then perform a simple GROUP-BY query on a result of the above query, using MIN and MAX functions:

```
SELECT min( tstamp ) as min_tstamp,
       max( tstamp ) as max_tstamp
FROM (
   SELECT tstamp, 
          SUM( CASE WHEN lag_in_sec >= interval '60' second THEN 1 ELSE 0 END )
          OVER (order by tstamp) as group_number
   FROM ( 
      SELECT *, tstamp - lag( tstamp ) Over (order by tstamp) as lag_in_sec
      FROM Table1234
   ) x
) y
GROUP BY group_number
ORDER BY 1

+----------------------+---------------------+
|     min_tstamp,      |     max_tstamp      |
+----------------------+---------------------+
| 2017-10-01 00:00:00, | 2017-10-01 00:00:20 |
| 2017-10-01 00:10:10, | 2017-10-01 00:10:20 |
+----------------------+---------------------+
```

Live demo: [DBFiddle link](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=42b16c60b6be84274077c3fd3b102e73)